# unable to call a c# method from javascript using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I have a c# method which I would like to call on client side.
I used ajax calling to achieve this

```
function ValidateIfDuplicate()
        {
            debugger

            var billtext = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_textBoxBillNumber").val();
            var retailer= $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_dropDownListRetailers").val();
            var billdate = $("#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_textBoxBillDate").val();

            if (billtext == "")
            {
                alert("Bill Number cannot be left empty");
                return false;
            }
            else if (retailer == 0) {
                alert("Please select a Retailer");
                return false;
            }
            else if (billdate == '') {
                alert("Date cannot be left empty");
                return false;
            }
            else if (billtext != '' && retailer != '' && billdate != '')
            {


                    $.ajax({
                        Type: "POST",
                        url: "CAInvoiceEntry.aspx/ValidateDuplicateEntry",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        data: { billtext1: billtext, billdate1: billdate, retailer1: retailer },
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            debugger
                            alert(result.d);
                        }
                    });

                return true;
            }
        }
```

and this is my c# method

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] 
public partial class CAInvoiceEntry: BaseClass
{
    [WebMethod, ScriptMethod()]
        public static int ValidateDuplicateEntry(string billtext1, string billdate1, string retailer1)
        {
            string validatebill = objCAInvoiceEntry.validatebilldate(textBoxBillNumber.Text, billdate1.ToString(), ViewState[AppConstants.UploadedBy].ToString(), dropDownListRetailers.SelectedValue);
            if (validatebill == "1")
            {

                return 1;
            }
            else
                return 0;
        }
}
```

but the web method is not fired. 
I have also tried using pagemethods.methodname() as an alternative(by registring the script with enablepagemethods=true) but with no effect.

If someone can guide me on where i am doing it wrong?
Just to be clear..
in the below image you can see the breakpoint execution, where the ajax call gets skipped.
[image]

Comment: try adding this     [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] on the class in which this method is located

Comment: What you get on browser `console`?

Comment: @guruprasad rao There is nothing that i get on the browser, when I debug and verify, the control doesn't pass to the method.

Comment: Then this purely `WebMethod` issue. Try searching on how you can call `WebMethod` through `javascript`.. You will get some solution..

Comment: @GuruprasadRao I went through all the websites and i find no difference in the way they have mentioned and the way i have called the method.

Comment: just fyi,in the url, the method that i am calling is in the direct .cs of the aspx page that i am writing my ajax calling. so i even tried url:"mypage.aspx/mymethod". But no use.

Comment: @mysterio even after adding scriptservice declartion for class it does not work

Comment: your method needs to be public

Comment: damn just remembered. the method has to be static to work. else you cant make an ajax call to it. If you make it static then you can only call static methods inside your function. Is  "validatebilldate" a static function.

Comment: @mysterio tried that as well with no result :) Thanks for the suggetions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be as issue with the way you are passing parameters through ajax.
Try this.

```
if (billtext != '' && retailer != '' && billdate != '')
            {

               debugger

               $.ajax({
                   type: "POST",
                   url: "CAInvoiceEntry.aspx/ValidateDuplicateEntry",
                   data: "{ billtext1:" + "'" + billtext + "'" + ", billdate1:" + "'" + billdate + "'" + ", retailer1:" + "'" + retailer + "'" + "}",
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: "json",
                   async: true,
                   cache: false,
                   success: function (msg) {
                       if (msg == "1")
                                       alert("Already exists");
                                   else
                                       alert("valid");
                   },
                   error: function (msg) {
                       debugger;
                       alert(msg);
                   }
               })
               return false;


            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing similar issue today. In my case i had `RouteConfig` in App_start folder, So i solved my problem by commenting this line

`//settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;`

which was the cause of the problem.

also **Your web method needs to be public and static**.

something like

```
public static int MethodName()
{
    // your method
}
```

Comment: i am not using MVC, so in my case this doesn't apply. Thank you. if any other suggestion it would be great

Comment: well i also wasn't using MVC, you can also use `RouteConfig` in Webforms, however for your issue please check Updated Answer

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny typo in your javascript.  Remember that javascript is case-sensitive.  You are passing in:

```
Type: "POST"
```

But in fact you should be passing in:

```
type: "POST"
```

If you use F12 on the Network tab, you will noticed that your current AJAX call is making a GET request, not a POST request.